# Is there some way to suggest a new feature to be added to CSS?

Tags: css, viewport-units

I have this idea for new relative CSS units; they are similar to 'vh' and 'vw' units but instead of being relative to the dimensions of the viewport, they would be relative to the dimensions of the parent element. Therefore it could be easier to create 'divs' with specific aspect ratios, and probably make life easier for CSS purists.

Anyway I would really appreciate some help to make this idea come true and this could also come in handy for others who also have feature ideas.

Comment: By discussing about that topic on the mailing list or forum of w3c. [How to suggest a specification to w3c?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297879/how-to-suggest-a-specification-to-w3c)

Comment: Check [CSS current work
& how to participate](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work.en.html)

Comment: I think CSS <percentage> do the same thing...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage

Comment: Yes but you still can't use a height percentage for a width and vice versa.

Comment: You could use [aspect-ratio](https://caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio) on a div, one example would be to set the `max-width: 30rem;` and `width: 100%;` to do the same what you are asking for. That is just one example of a few combinations on how to do something like that.

Comment: These are called  "container dimensions". See https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5888

Comment: This is already under way. https://css-tricks.com/next-gen-css-container/